# Powershell: how to compare 2 $xml variables to see if their xml content is the same?

Tags: xml, powershell, compare

I've got 2 System.Xml.XmlDocument variables, $xml1 and $xml2, how to compare them to see if their xml content is identical?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method in the DOM implementation to do that in .NET, however LINQ to XML has https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.deepequals%28v=vs.110%29.aspx to compare to LINQ to XML `XNode` objects: `XNode.DeepEquals(XDocument.Load(new XmlNodeReader($xml1)), XDocument.Load(new XmlNodeReader($xml2)))`.